# Format date as the first/last day of the month

Tags: php

I have date strings in "Y-m" format. Day is irrelevant here. Now I need to create another date from these date strings wheere day should be either 1st or the last day of the month. I have tried this code:

```
$curDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', $datestring1);
$dt =  $curDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

The problem here is that it creates dates with the current day of the months. How can I force it to do it for the 1st or last day?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first day:

```
$dt = $curDate->format('Y-m-01');
```

last day:

```
$dt = $curDate->format('Y-m-t');
```

---

> **t:** Number of days in the given month

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

You can specify hard code value

```
$curDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', $datestring1);
$dt =  $curDate->format('Y-m-1'); //if you want first day
$dt =  $curDate->format('Y-m-t'); //if you want last day
```

Comment: Using 31 won't work for months where the day is less than 31, such as February and April.